# activity_main.xml shows a change in my design view in android studio when I change code but in app there is no change, whats going on?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, banner-ads

I previously had a banner app in my app which overlapped the bottom part of my app but now I changed it so that the banner app as its separate space at the bottom of the app so it doesn't overlap the bottom part of my app page. A change is shown in my design view in my activity_main.xml page when I added the new code but when I ran the app there was no change. I even uninstalled the app and reinstalled it with the new code but still no change. Does anyone know what is going on?
This is my previous code of the banner ad:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

And this is my new banner ad code:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Check your ```xml``` file name and make sure it matches the one you set in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml layout name and check it again

Comment: what do you mean by my xml layout name?

Comment: yes sometimes in multi module projects or in big projects, you maybe call wrong xml layout that has the same name